# Making Wing IDE wrap lines on one file

Tags: ide, word-wrap, wing-ide

I have one file in my project, (the readme file,) which I would like Wing IDE to display with wrapped lines. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it's currently not possible.

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is possible. Here's how you would do this:

Edit > Preferences > Editor > Line Wrapping

In this window, make sure that the "Wrap Long Lines" box is checked. You can then edit settings in the same window like at what position the line show wrap, etc.

Comment: I asked about doing it on one file.

Answer (score 1):

Source -> Justify text will reflow one paragraph of text.  Unfortuneatly you have to invoke it one paragraph at a time if you want the whole file reformatted.

I realize you may actually be looking for a viewing transformation that does not modify the file.